# Dojo data-dojo-type attribute does not work with struts 2 form

Tags: ajax, struts2, dojo

I have upgraded from dojo 1.5 to dojo 1.8.1. Unfortunately struts form does not work as expected. Here is my html:

```
<s:form id="formId" action="my.action"
        cssClass="floatForm" theme="css_xhtml"
        data-dojo-type="MyForm" targets="target">
```

MyForm is a custom type which inherits from dijit/form/Form. postCreate method is never called for this type. Basically it works as if there was no data-dojo-type attribute. However if I change data-dojo-type to dojoType or <s:form to simply <form everything works as expected.

I'm using struts 2.3.4 and dojo 1.8.1.

Can anyone say if I am doing something wrong? Why data-dojo-type is ignored with struts form? Thanks!